# Can't work out if this proof is sound or not. Any ideas?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed space over some field $\mathbb K$. I proved that

$$ \overline{B_r(a)} = \{v \in V \mid \|v-a\| \le r \}$$

$\subseteq $ was easy but for the $\supseteq$ direction I am really not sure what is going on.

> Please could someone tell me if this proof is wrong? And if it is,
>   why?

My idea was this:

Let $x \in \overline{B_r (a)}^c$ and $S=\{v \in V \mid \|v-a\| \le r \}$. Since $\overline{B_r (a)}^c$ is open there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_\varepsilon (x) \subset \overline{B_r (a)}^c$. Hence $\|x-a\| \ge r + \varepsilon > r$ hence $x \in S^c$.

My problem with this is:

It seems to be independent of the fact that $V$ is linear. But the statement is false in arbitrary metric spaces.

In the meantime I made an alternative proof which works but I still want to know what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(x)\subset \overline{B_r(a)}^c$ does not imply $||x-a||\geq r+\epsilon>r$. This implication is not justified by the open-ness of $\overline{B_r(a)}^c$. You want this to say that $x$ is at least $\epsilon$ distance away from $\partial \overline{B_r(a)}$.  This is the intuitive idea from drawing pictures, but of course drawing pictures doesn't really work for general metric spaces. You're implicitly using the idea that $\partial {B_r(a)}=\{v\in V: ||v-a||=r\}=\partial\overline{B_r(a)}$, which is *not* true in general metric spaces (the discrete space is the obvious counterexample, since the boundary of the ball $B_1(x)$ is empty). That's why the proof is wrong: $x\in \overline{B_r(a)}^c$ does not mean $d(x,a)>r$ in general metric spaces.

This statement is fixable for normed spaces as long as you show that $\partial {B_r(a)}=\{v\in V: ||v-a||=r\}$, although at this point the statement becomes obvious.